# Tap not working if SVG Image inside UIControl

Tags: ios, swift, svg, uicontrol

I am writing an **iOS App** in **Swift 4**.

I need a **custom button** with **SVG image** inside it.

So, I added **UIView** in Storyboard scene >  Changed it to **UIControl** as custom class > **Traits**: **Button** and **User interaction Enabled**.
Then I added **SVGView** (**[Macaw](https://github.com/exyte/Macaw)**) inside it, Constraints 0,0,0,0 and unchecked all of its traits.

The issue is this button isn't taking any **tap (TouchUpInside)** gestures.

Comment: you want to make an image act like a button, right?

Comment: Right i want a button, with SVG image in it

Comment: you can take a button and use the svg image as a button background , and another way to do this to use tap gesture.so that when you tap on that image it will act like an button.

Answer (score 0):

check is user interaction enabled for the image?

Comment: Checked, its turned off